# Neo4j how to create a new node when db is running

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I don't know how to create a new node in Neo4j when database is running. I've tried this:

```
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(new File(DB_PATH))
```

but it appears an error with lock file (because db is running). What is the proper way to do this? I've found some posts with using newEmbeddedDatabase with only path, not new File, but it doesn't work, it needs File. For queries and saving I use extending the GraphRepository, but it doesn't work with creating new Nodes.